# gotoDate do not take into account calendar.options.firstDay in 2.1.1

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

firstDay was working with this method in 1.6.3 but not in 2.1.1

Steps:

1-  setting firstDay using:

```
 $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getView').calendar.options.firstDay = n;
```

2 - And then moving to a specific date:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate, new Date());
```

Expected:
Calendar moves to the new date, rendering the calendar with the firstDay set in step1.

Plunker with version 1.6.3 Working.
http://plnkr.co/edit/Onw9wb?p=preview

Plunker with version 2.1.1 NOT working. 
http://plnkr.co/edit/9QkiNK?p=preview

Differences on code:

- Dependency on moment.js
- Receiving a moment instead of a date at fullCalendar('getDate')

I've open an issue, but probably somebody has an idea here. Thx!
https://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=2343&thanks=2343&ts=1415201096

Comment: Don't think you should set first day like that. It's not intended to be used that way

Comment: This was a solution in 1.6.3 without .fullcalendar('destroy'). Any proposal?

Comment: Only the destroy way is officially supported